# *ngIf not working inside the Modal

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, ngx-bootstrap

i used the *ngif on a button that will be false and came true when the item is selectd from ng-select but its not working

here is the button code

```
  <button *ngIf="switch" (click)="productSaveInCart()" type="button" class="col  matbuton " mat-button>
          ADD to Cart
        </button>
```

and here is the whole code of Modal

```
  <ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{modaldata.i.i}}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close btn pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef2.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <mat-card style="margin: 0; ">
      <img height="400px" style="width: 110%" mat-card-image [src]="modaldata.i.t || '../../assets/images/noimage.png'">
      <mat-card-footer class="row">

        <h4>Extra prep. time: 1hr</h4>

        <ng-select [allowClear]="true" [items]="items" [disabled]="disabled" (data)="refreshValue($event)" (selected)="selected($event)"
          (removed)="removed($event)" (typed)="typed($event)" placeholder="No Date selcted">
        </ng-select>
        <div *ngFor="let item of list ">
          <h4 class="col">{{item.n}}</h4>
          <app-dropdowns #child class="col" [listdata]="item"></app-dropdowns>
        </div>
        <button *ngIf="switch" (click)="productSaveInCart()" type="button" class="col  matbuton " mat-button>
          ADD to Cart
        </button>
      </mat-card-footer>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: Where is the typescript controlling `switch`?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(selected)="selected($event);switch=true"
```

you can use hidden that way: it should work

```
[hidden]="switch"
```

Comment: can you please explain what the logic behind this ?

Comment: on select event you can set switch to "true" and thus the button ADD TO CART will be visible

Comment: i know ...but why its not become visible if i change it in my component.ts file

Comment: try declare the variable switch globally, or use [hidden] it works perfect in that case. i will update the answer

Comment: Still, the question is, how it's working in and not the standard angular way.